# How to change WebPart appearance Title (WP Properties) using JSLink?

Tags: office-365, jquery, jslink, list-view-web-part

**Is it possible to change the Title of the List View WebPart (Title property under Appearance) using JSLink i.e using `overrideCtx` properties**? At present, I am modifying the Title using `$('span:contains("<Title>")').html("<New Title>")` but the styling is not retained (for both preRender and postRender method).

Comment: Did you add jQuery before running this script? You might also check whether you should run it on document.ready

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the *HTML* of WebPart `Title`, your jQuery should not work. *HTML* of WebPart `Title` looks like.

```
<span title="Project List" id="WebPartTitleWPQ3" class="js-webpart-titleCell">
 <h2 style="text-align:justify;" class="ms-webpart-titleText">
   <a accesskey="W" href="/Projects/Lists/Project%20List">
    <nobr>
      <span>Project List</span>
      <span id="WebPartCaptionWPQ3"></span>
    </nobr>
  </a>
 </h2>
</span>
```

So now you can try something like following as it worked for me. As you want to use `overrideCtx` properties, so the code should go under `OnPostRender`

```
 OnPostRender: function(ctx) { 
        $('.ms-webpart-titleText a span:contains("Project List")').text("new title");
       }
```

Comment: Thanks, but the jQuery code $('span:contains("<Title>")').html("<New Title>") is working as it will find the <span>Project List</span> and replace the text. The problem with this approach is that the text will lose all its styling. I was wondering if we can use any of the "ctx" properties.

Comment: Did you try my code? I did not lose anything. ` $('span:contains("<Title>")').html("<New Title>")` this selector is not valid. Use mine `$('.ms-webpart-titleText a span:contains("Project List")')`.

Comment: Yep. you are right. The styling is intact when using your code. Thanks. Just wondering if there is no property of ctx which i can use?

Comment: No, CSR governs the contents of the webpart, not the webpart itself

Comment: if you had used `$('element').text()` instead of `$(element).html()` and selected the inner most node containing the title text you would also not have altered the styling

Answer (score 2):

For targetting individual WebParts on one screen, and without jQuery

```
document.querySelector(["#WebPartTitleWPQ2 nobr>span"]).innerHTML="New Title"
```